# Why do string-to-int functions (e.g. strtol(), atoi(), sscanf()) keep returning 0 when given array of hex values?

Tags: arrays, c, string, integer, hex

**Problem:**

I am making a file interpretation program that needs to read/write Hexadecimal values. At times, there will be a section of hexadecimal that needs to be read as one long hex value, rather than 2 different ones. (E.G {0x00, 0x01} == 0x0001 or just 1). I am able to get these values into an array just fine, which is why I will be thinking of 'memcmp()' and 'memcpy()' when I sleep tonight. The problem occurs when I need to convert the array of hexadecimal to one int value I can use. Every time I use a string-to-int function, like atoi(), it will always return 0.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    signed char data[] = {0x00, 0x01};
    signed char res;
    res = strtol((char *)data, NULL, 16);
    printf("RES: %d", res);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason I use `signed char` as my datatype is because I want to save on memory, without storing all my data as something like a `long` without need and also because the values I have set as `signed char` will never go up past 100.

**What I've Tried:**
I have tried many different ways of getting this to work, like using different functions, and different datatypes, but in the end, all that happens is I get 0.

*atoi:*

```
...
char data[] = {0x00, 0x01};
int res = atoi(data);
printf("VALUE: %d", res);
...
```

or *sscanf:*

```
...
char data[] = {0x00, 0x01};
int res;
sscanf(data, "%d", &res); // Also tried "%02x" but to no avail.
printf("VALUE: %d", res);
...
```

**Expected:**
`printf()` Should print out "VALUE: 1"

**Result:**'
Prints out "VALUE: 0"

**EDIT: ANSWER**
Turns out I was mixed up and misunderstood. What I should have been doing was getting the ASCII equivalent of the number I needed, instead of using the number 1 and expecting the char '1' to appear.

Instead of 0x01, it should have been 0x31, and would have to use bitwise operators to achieve my goal.

Comment: `data` is an empty string, since the first character is the null terminator. What are you expecting as the result?

Comment: What makes you believe the string `"\x00\x01"` will convert to a valid integer? As @Barmar points out the first character is a `\0`, so it's actually just an empty `""` string.

Comment: I think what you actually want to use is bit operations to shift and combine the two bytes, not `strtoul()`.

Comment: Something like `data[0] << 4 | data[1]`

Comment: @DarkAtom I tried with 0x01 and I still get the same result of 0 instead of 1. In my other program, I made it so it takes directly from a non-empty array, and when I print out 1 character of the array, it works fine. It's when I convert it to int.

Comment: @Barmar I will try in just a second, my coding habitat has been taken over by some hooligans.

Comment: Why would you expect `0x01` to work any better? The `strtoX` functions are for parsing the textual representation of numbers, so the elements of the array should be character codes that correspond to digits. E.g. `'0' == 0x30, '1' == 0x31`, etc.

Comment: @Primitive You are confusing strings with characters. A string is a set of characters terminated with the byte 0. Here, 0x01 is a byte and may be a character inside a string, but then this would be the control character SOH (ASCII number 1). In any case, 0x01 is NOT he string "0x01" if this what you want to convert.

Comment: @Primitive I think you confuse byte arrays with strings. To get the value 1 out of `atoi` you need to pass an array such as `0x31, 0x00`, or the string "1". To get the value 1 out of the `0x00, 0x01` array, you need to manually mask and shift the answer: `value = (data[0] << 4) | data[1];`.

Comment: For example, the string `"35"` is the array `{0x33, 0x35, 0x00}`

Comment: @DarkAtom yeah you were right on the money, I got confused, and now I will be letting my wife and kids know that I have solved the forbidden hex crisis of 2023 and it's thanks to DarkAtom. I'll try telling them that anyway, after I get this restraining order off of me :3

Comment: * I want to save on memory* - Are you living in the 1980s or programming for a PIC? Worrying about such miniscule use of memory as `signed char` instead of `int` is a waste of time and effort with current processors and average installed RAM. Premature optimization is a total waste of time that could be better spent adding features to your program.

Comment: I don't need to relax. I'm already relaxed. Chill out - because someone gave you information doesn't mean you need to think it's a personal insult. If you let nothing get to you here, you're not going to last long. Wasting time and energy trying to avoid using a couple of bytes of memory is just foolish, and there's nothing *optimized* about doing it. Computers allocate and move memory in blocks nowadays, not bytes. You're programming like you're using an old 8088 CPU with 640K of RAM - it's like powering your car with your feet like Fred Flintstone while we drive turbo-powered cars.

Comment: Also, for a better use of your time, learn about the functions you're trying to use. They all expect null-terminated strings, not char arrays. You're not calling them properly, which is why they're not working as expected. The time you're using worrying about being *optimized* could better be spent reading the documentation for the functions.

Comment: @KenWhite That's really not a good comparison of things by just using a different datatype. I could care less if it's just a couple of bytes I save, I like to use these datatypes anyway since I feel much more control over my program and also helps me learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{0x00, 0x01} == 0x0001` indicates that your binary representation received from somewhere is big endian

To have it as a signed int number you need to use bitwise operations.

```
int16_t toInt2Bytes(void *buff)
{
    unsigned char *uc = buff;

    return (uint16_t)uc[1] | ((uint16_t)(uc[0]) << 8);
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[] = {0x00, 0x01};
    char arr1[] = {0x80, 0x00};

    printf("%d\n", toInt2Bytes(arr));
    printf("%d\n", toInt2Bytes(arr1));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aMGnrxosv

> Every time I use a string-to-int function, like atoi(), it will always
> return 0.

Those functions require ***strings*** and your data is not a string. You cant use them.